# Custom column for creditmemo in magento

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento EE 1.14.2.
I need new column "custom_id" in both creditmemos and invoices. So I made an installer:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$alter = "
 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_invoice ADD COLUMN custom_id VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE COMMENT 'custom increment_id';
 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_invoice_grid ADD COLUMN custom_id VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE COMMENT 'custom increment_id';

 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_creditmemo ADD COLUMN custom_id VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE COMMENT 'custom increment_id';
 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_creditmemo_grid ADD COLUMN custom_id VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE COMMENT 'custom increment_id';
 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_creditmemo ADD COLUMN rma_increment_id VARCHAR(255);
 ALTER TABLE sales_flat_creditmemo ADD INDEX (rma_increment_id);
";
$installer->run($alter);

$installer->endSetup();
```

When I'm saving invoice like this:

```
$object->setCustomId($customId);
$object->save();
```

row in table sales_flat_invoice_grid also updates... But when I'm saving a creditmemo in the same way, sales_flat_creditmemo_grid it's not updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted more code :). There was a problem with transactions ...

Old code:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$connection->beginTransaction();
$object->setCustomId($customId);
$object->save();
$incrementModel->setIncrementId($newIncrementId);
$incrementModel->save();
$connection->commit();
```

New code:

```
$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$object->setCustomId($customId);
$transaction->addObject($object);
$incrementModel->setIncrementId($newIncrementId);
$transaction->addObject($incrementModel);
$transaction->save();
```

Old code caused that save() didn't run afterSave() method ...